# How handle clicks on view and button at same time?

Tags: react-native

Ok, so I want to know if there is possible to handle a click on a button and a overlay view at the same time (trigger onPress of Button and of View/TouchableHighlight)

Because it's not possible just putting two objects one on top of other, cause it's make just the higher one (on zIndex) clickable, but never the two at same time.

https://prntscr.com/p80uhl "view of app"

https://prntscr.com/p80uj9 "the zIndex of Components"

https://prntscr.com/p814jm "Screenshot of React Native Page" (Result of Code)

The Code: (I removed some functions to show just the important)

```js
// ... Imports 

export default class TableConfig extends Component {

  state = {
    selected: -1,
    // Other States
  }

  select = id => {
    console.log('SELECTED: '+id);

    //Change Selected and the Text
    this.setState(() => ({ selected: id, selectedText: this.state.blocks[id].text }));
  }

  unselect = () => {
    console.log('UNSELECTED!');

    //Change State & Hide Component
    this.setState(()=>{});
  }

  render(){
    const { option } = this.state;
    let select = this.select;

    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>

        { /* The Overlay */ }
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.full} onPress={()=>{this.unselect}}/>

        { /* That a Table of Buttons Basically (A grid of 2x2 Buttons) */ }
        <Card flat style={styles.all}>
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <TableBlock text={this.state.blocks[0].text} color={this.state.blocks[0].color} icon={this.state.blocks[0].icon} onClick={() => {select(0)}}/>
            <TableBlock text={this.state.blocks[1].text} color={this.state.blocks[1].color} icon={this.state.blocks[1].icon} onClick={() => {select(1)}}/>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.row}>
            <TableBlock text={this.state.blocks[2].text} color={this.state.blocks[2].color} icon={this.state.blocks[2].icon} onClick={() => {select(2)}}/>
            <TableBlock text={this.state.blocks[3].text} color={this.state.blocks[3].color} icon={this.state.blocks[3].icon} onClick={() => {select(3)}}/>
          </View>
        </Card>

        { /* This is the component that I want to hide select if the user clicked outside of this */}
        <Card flat row style={styles.bottom}>
          {
            (option=='none')?<TableConfigs handler={this.change}/>:
            (option=='color')?<ColorConfig handler={this.change} color={this.changeColor}/>:
            (option=='icon')?<IconConfig handler={this.change} modal={this.setVisibility}/>:
            (option=='text')?<TextConfig handler={this.change} text={this.state.selectedText} setText={this.setText}/>:
            (option=='audio')?<AudioConfig handler={this.change} editting={this.state.selected} recordTime={this.state.recordTime} changeTime={this.changeTime}/>:null
          }
        </Card>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  //Other Styles ...

  full: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    opacity: 0.2,
    zIndex: 12,
    elevation: 20,
  },

});
```

Comment: You could use a ref on the button and manually trigger a click when the overlay is clicked.  Can I ask why you want this functionality?

Comment: I'm just trying to detect when the user click outside a component. I search and find some posts here in StackOverflow saying about that but the answer not work as desired.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I'll put on the question.

Comment: @RutherfordWonkington I edited the Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put the overlay below the button?
It sounds more appropriate for your use case.
This way you can handle both the click on the button and the click outside the button (the overlay)